Quiero hacer dos listas de productos separandolas por su categoria
Si tengo muchos libros los cuales son de estudio y otros de entretenimiento y los quiero clasificar en dos listas. Entretenimiento y otra estudio. Como lo hago con javascript

Quizás sería bueno que explicaras lo que tienes y lo que quieres, agregar algo de código para dar contexto. Así los que no somos adivinos ni telepatas también podemos participar.

Hola Veronica, bienvenida, comparto el comentario de Yussef, se me ocurre que podrías implementar una clase Libro con un atributo categoria y en base a este último, ir clasificandolos.

para poder ayudarte tienes que compartir la fuente de los datos de los libros ...
estan en una base de datos, como los obtienes?
ya estan en una lista(select) de html, como los obtienes?

incluso necesitas presentar un ejemplo de lo que has intentado

Respondo esta pregunta con el afán de introducir algunos conceptos básicos de la programación en javascript.
El ejemplo que encontrarás más abajo, está construido sobre las siguientes bases:

Primero defino una Clase de javascript Libro. Las clases son plantillas para la creación de objetos. Esto me permite crear objetos de tipo Libro que van a tener dos atributos, titulo y categoría. Usaremos la categoría para filtrar realizar el filtrado que es el objetivo de la práctica.
La clase tiene un constructor, que asigna los atributos iniciales de cada  objeto que vamos creando. Invocamos a ese constructor con la palabra reservada new seguida del nombre de la clase y, entre paréntesis, los parámetros que le pasamos al constructor.

Luego, creo una variable libros, que es un array de objetos de tipo Libro. Los libros que estarán en ese arreglo los voy creando allí mismo en la definición de la variable.
Al final de la sentencia, esta variable va a tener 5 libros, 3 de estudio y 2 de entretenimiento.

Creo una nueva variable llamada librosEstudio. Para llenarla, me valgo del método filter() del arreglo.
Este método recibe como parámetro una función que se va a ejecutar una vez por cada elemento del arreglo. Esta función acepta un parámetro que es el libro que está evaluando y debe devolver un valor booleano. Verdadero si el libro pasa el filtro, y falso si no lo pasa.
El resultado de todo el método filter va a ser un nuevo arreglo que contiene los elementos que SI pasaron el filtro.
La función de flecha que paso como parámetro va a devolver verdadero si se cumple la condición libro.categoria === "Estudio", es decir, nos quedamos con los libros que tienen categoría "Estudio" y descartamos todos los demás.

Finalmente, imprimo a la consola el arreglo resultante de esta operación de filtrado y contenido en la variable librosEstudio.


Puedes probar el script haciendo clic en el botón "Ejecutar"


class Libro {
  constructor(titulo, categoria) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.categoria = categoria;
  }
}

let libros = [
  new Libro("Javascript for doomies", "Estudio"), 
  new Libro("Blancanieves", "Entretenimiento"), 
  new Libro("Object Pascal Handbook", "Estudio"), 
  new Libro("La caperucita roja", "Entretenimiento"), 
  new Libro("OmniThread library", "Estudio"), 
];

let librosEstudio = libros.filter((libro) => libro.categoria === "Estudio");
console.log(librosEstudio);



Sugiero que tomes este código y hagas el esfuerzo de entender cada una de sus partes. Puedes ir leyendo el código y regresar a leer mi explicación las veces que haga falta. También puedes ir haciendo modificaciones, a manera de jugar con él.
Por ejemplo, agrega dos o tres libros más al momento de construir el arreglo libros y observa el resultado que produce.
Ahora, crea una nueva variable y un nuevo filtro para que esta contenga los libros de entretenimiento.
Listo, tienes la tarea completa.
Si eres curiosa, ahora agrega libros con una tercera categoría, digamos, "Cocina".
Crea una nueva variable y un filtro para que esta se quede con todos los libros que no sean de entretenimiento, es decir, cocina y estudio.
Investiga otras maneras de hacer lo mismo, por ejemplo, crea un arreglo de libros de cocina y otro de libros de estudio, y ahora busca la manera de crear un tercer arreglo que sea la suma de los dos arreglos anteriores.
La idea es que vayas aprendiendo y también te vayas divirtiendo en el proceso, espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda en ese proceso. Si solo copias y pegas el código, habrás perdido esa oportunidad. Depende de tí ahora.
